# AMCharts How to color bullets by value?

Tags: javascript, php, amcharts

I am working with amcharts and I tried to color bullets in the chart by the values they have. So I created an array in javascript and passed the values from the database into it. Green is just a value for testing.

```
   var chartData = [
      <?php
         foreach($tmp as $row)
           {
             echo'{"Wahrscheinlichkeit":'.$row[3].',"Schaden":'.$row[4].',"value":1,"Beschreibung":"'.$row[2].'", "Color":"Green"},'; 
           }
      ?>
   ];
```

Here I create the chart:

```
 chart = new AmCharts.AmXYChart();
 chart.dataProvider = chartData;
```

Here I draw the chart:

```
 var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.valueField = "value"; // größe der Kugeln
            graph.xField = "Wahrscheinlichkeit";
            graph.yField = "Schaden";
            graph.maxBulletSize=20;
            graph.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph.bullet = "circle";
            graph.bulletColor= "[[Color]]";
            graph.balloonText = "Wahrscheinlichkeit:<b>[[x]]</b> Schaden:<b>[[y]]</b><br>Beschreibung:<b> [[Beschreibung]]</b>"
            chart.addGraph(graph);
```

At the point "bulletcolor" I try to get the color out of the array, but it doesn't work.

```
chart.write("chartdiv");
```

Looking forward getting tips and help from you

Answer (score 2):

"bulletColor" can't reference fields in data like this.

Instead, please use "lineColorField":

http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#lineColorField

I.e.:

```
var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph.valueField = "value"; // größe der Kugeln
graph.xField = "Wahrscheinlichkeit";
graph.yField = "Schaden";
graph.maxBulletSize=20;
graph.lineAlpha = 0;
graph.bullet = "circle";
graph.lineColorField = "Color";
graph.balloonText = "Wahrscheinlichkeit:<b>[[x]]</b> Schaden:<b>[[y]]</b><br>Beschreibung:<b> [[Beschreibung]]</b>"
chart.addGraph(graph);
```

Comment: This the only way to do it with AmXYChart, Thanks!